# Align list item to the left in unordered list

Tags: html, css

I have the following html and css:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>li1</li>
    <li>li2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
}

#wrapper ul
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#wrapper ul li
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;   
}
```

Which results in the following unordered list:

[image]

How do I align the list-items to the left in the unordered list?

I've tried float and margin in the "#wrapper ul li", but that doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: You need to provide more code. http://jsfiddle.net/cYZtA/ is what you have given, which does not correspond to the result you have provided.

Comment: What is the css style for your wrapper div?

Comment: Css style for wrapper div now included in question

Comment: Try #wrapper ul { margin: 0px .... }

Comment: margin: 0px didn't solve it :-/

Comment: Might be some other elements on your page filling that space. Do you show what other elements are there on your page. Does your BODY tag has any padding or margin set?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add a `padding-left: 0pt` to the `#wrapper ul` block:

```
#wrapper ul
{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    list-style-type:none;
    ' CHECK THE NEXT LINE '
    padding-left: 0pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your unordered list markers need to be put **outside**:

```
#wrapper ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to decrease padding-left of your UL element. If it won't help, play with padding-left and margin-left of UL and LI.